# how to join from a belongs_to model to a has_many table from the controller or view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have two very simple models, Clients and Appointments:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :first_name, presence: true
  validates :last_name, presence: true
  validates :copay, numericality: { only_integer: true }

  has_many :appointments
end

class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :clients
end
```

What I'd like to do is show all of the Clients that have appointments in the index page. It makes more sense to me to try to do this through the Applications controller. Something like this:

```
  def index
    @appointments = Appointment.client.all
  end
```

But I can't quite figure out the right way to do it. In the Clients controller it makes sense to do something like this:

```
@clients = Client.all(:include => :appointments)
```

What's the way to do the reverse (i.e. pull clients into appointments)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you all clients that have appointments:

```
@clients = Client.joins(:appointments)
```

I don't think it makes sense at all to do this in your `ApplicationController`. Since you want to display that list in a specific page, you should do it in `clients#index` or `appointments#index`.

Comment: the plan was to do it in appointments#index. I must not have been clear. Does that mean Appointment.joins(:clients) would work the same?